# Does Terra Nova end on a cliffhanger?

Tags: tv, terra-nova

I was looking for a show to watch this summer and there will be a french translation of [Terra Nova](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1641349/) that will air soon. Through further reading, I learned that Season 2 was [cancelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_%28TV_series%29#Cancellation).

I hate starting a show that is canceled before its real end. But it's even worse when you are left on a cliffhanger, with no hope of getting a proper end. Also, the cancellation of a show occurs for [Good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defying_Gravity_%28TV_series%29), [Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprica_%28TV_series%29), and [Ugly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_%28TV_series%29) reasons.

I would like to avoid to reading anything that would reveal spoilers. So, does Terra Nova first and unique season end on a cliffhanger? Is it worth watching even knowing there will be nothing after the first season?

Comment: I assume you mean a *cliffhanger*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of this writing, the show is cancelled.  They tried shopping it around to other networks and online outlets like Netflix, but the show was super expensive so no one picked it up.  When they filmed the finale, they didn't know that it was getting cancelled, so it was written as a season (not series) finale.

The final episodes introduce a new major faction from the future, and they heavily impact the status quo.  The final episode has the main characters largely resolving the issues the other faction introduced.  However, it doesn't completely resolve the story.  Terra Nova is left in a moderately precarious state, and it's clear the other faction has plans that would have made them more of a threat in season 2.  In terms of cliffhangeriness, I'd say it's maybe a 5 out of 10, there are plenty of unresolved plot lines, but no major cliffhanger that you'll wonder about.

Some details on what the second season would have contained can be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85767/1027).

Comment: Good work on explaining the situation without giving any real spoilers.  Wish I could +5 this one for that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched the show and have no particular plans to, but based on the episode summary: it sounds as though it ends with a setup for a second season, but not necessarily a nailbiting cliffhanger.

As of May, Fox and Netflix had passed on picking up season 2, but the production company was still trying to shop the show to other networks.