# Can anyone get any information on the cliffhanger in Terra Nova involving the wooden prow?

Tags: terra-nova

What information have the showrunners released about what it might be please tell me because the second series of the show was cancelled and it seems unlikely it will be released on another network.  What were the plans for the second season of *Terra Nova*?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find anything specific to the wooden prow, but the implication seemed to be that the wormhole had occurred before, possibly even as a natural occurrence. This makes a lot of sense as a plot point, because from a writing standpoint it would allow for the following:

- Other pockets of humans on the alternate Earth, possibly even descendants of earlier settlers from previous Earth centuries
- A possible means of returning to Earth or of renewed conflict between the settlers and their modern Earth

As far as ideas/guesses, both [show executive Brannon Braga](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/s158/terra-nova/news/a408350/terra-nova-exec-reveals-scrapped-season-two-plans.html#~p9baIUekaTq4DU) as well as actor Stephen Lang have discussed what was to come in season 2:

Apparently in the second season, the settlers would venture out into The Badlands only to find that the oppressing army has been slaughtered by "highly intelligent dinosaurs". There would have also been a plot arc where Taylor goes a little nuts and Terra Nova finds itself divided into two factions - the Taylor supporters and the Shannon supporters, with both men struggling for ultimate control of the settlement.